# plugin unsupported: sqliteplugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build an offline app using cordova, I am using the sqlite plugin for storage. In my config.xml file i have added an entry, but when i build apk i am getting the error `Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: SQLitePlugin`

how can i resolve this?

here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.plusminus.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />  
  <name>DAPP</name>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="SQLitePlugin" value="io.liteglue.SQLitePlugin"/>
    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="aadd@xxxxxx.com">
        xxxxxxxx
    </author>

  <icon src="/lib/images/AppIcon.png" />

  <gap:platform name="android" />
  <access origin="*" />

</widget>
```

Comment: please check here http://www.santoshshinde.com/2015/03/integrate-sqlite-plugin-in-phonegap-for.html

Comment: @SantoshShinde is there any option to add plugin without cli? because i am not using cli.

Comment: Why you are not using CLI & which editor used to create the cordova project ?

Comment: @SantoshShinde i created the html and js from the scratch and added config.xml directly with the files and packaged it.

Comment: its not best way to create the cordova project because we have need others files also https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: @SantoshShinde Any how the html and js files can be moved once i create the project with cli right? i will try with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132667/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-mithun-raikar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to installed [sqlite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) via CLI.

Installed plugin by Just Open command prompt and go to your project path and install plugin using CLI

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
```

For more helps to check [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/integrate-sqlite-plugin-in-phonegap-for.html) & If you want add the customized plugin used plugman for that please look to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2016/11/steps-to-create-cordova-plugin.html)..

Hopes this will help you !!.